# What's this strange icon in IE10 img tags?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I am having this strange issue in IE10, where my site's social networking icons have a weird graphic on top of them:

[image]

I can't seem to get rid of them. I tried setting border, padding, margin, outline, all to zero, with no effect. Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="socialIcons">
    <a href="#"><img id="fbIcon" width="24" height="24" href="one.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="gpIcon" width="24" height="24" href="one.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="twIcon" width="24" height="24" href="one.png" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="piIcon" width="24" height="24" href="one.png" /></a>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
#socialIcons > a > img {
float:left;
width: 24px;
height: 24px;
background-image: url(../img/icons.png);
}
#gpIcon {
background-position: -24px 0;
}
#twIcon {
background-position: -48px 0;
}
#piIcon {
background-position: -72px 0;
}
```

one.png is a 1x1 transparent png. I am using sprites to draw the actual icons. I suspect this problem has something to do with the anchor tag, since the other images don't have this issue.

Comment: Looks like a missing image icon. Probably because your image tag is wrong.

Comment: Well props to IE in this case, who showed the error, unlike the other browsers, which failed silently.

Comment: Why are you using `img` tags here? It doesn't really make sense. Why don't by put all the styles directly onto the `a` tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<img id="fbIcon" width="24" height="24" href="one.png" />
```

should be

```
<img id="fbIcon" width="24" height="24" src="one.png" />
```

`img` Tag don't have `href` Attribute. Reference [W3C HTML/Elements/img](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/img)

Comment: Yeah, that was quite dumb of me. Your suggestion fixed it, thanks.

Comment: Actually, he is setting the image via CSS so it doesn't even need the `src` attribute.

Comment: @webnoob: In this case he should not be using an img tag in the first place.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Agreed.

Answer (score 3):

You are specifying the image via CSS. Unless you actually want two images you should not use an `<img>` tag at all - simply use CSS to show your `<a>` as `display: inline-block` and add the background image there.

Comment: I used a div with js behind this fixed the issue in both IE and Chrome. Chrome did not have the icon but displayed all title texts.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `<img>` tag with wrong attribute (`href`). Since you are using CSS to add images, you should follow the general practice of using `<span>`

```
<div id="socialIcons"> 
 <a href="#"><span id="fbIcon" width="24" height="24"  ></span></a>
 <a href="#"><span id="gpIcon" width="24" height="24"  ></span></a>
 <a href="#"><span id="twIcon" width="24" height="24"  ></span></a>
 <a href="#"><span id="piIcon" width="24" height="24"  ></span></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#socialIcons > a > span {
    float: left;
    width: 24px;
    height: 24px;
    background-image: url(../img/icons.png);
}
#gpIcon {
    background-position: -24px 0;
}
#twIcon {
    background-position: -48px 0;
}
#piIcon {
    background-position: -72px 0;
}
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NzLuF/) (tested on IE10)